# How can I handle my dataset with python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I had one input dataset name data.csv
the content is

```
id ,   name
1  ,  Jone/Elvis/Tom
2  ,  Elvis/Tonny
```

The name column use slash as seperator 
I need process the data.csv , my expected output is

```
id, Jone, Elvis, Tom, Toony
1,   1  ,  1   ,  1 ,  0
2,   0  ,  1   ,  0 ,  1
```

1 means column name had exists in name, 0 means not. 
How can I use python with pandas to transfer the input?

Answer (score 4):

Let's use pandas and `.str.get_dummies` with `sep` parameter:

Read in dataframe from clipboard

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+\,\s+')
df
```

Input Dataframe:

```
   id            name
0   1  Jone/Elvis/Tom
1   2     Elvis/Tonny
```

Set index and use string accessor with `get_dummies`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('id')    
df1['name'].str.get_dummies(sep='/').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id  Elvis  Jone  Tom  Tonny
0   1      1     1    1      0
1   2      1     0    0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
data["name"]= data["name"].str.split("/")

jone = [0, 0]
elvis = [0, 0]
tom = [0, 0]
tonny = [0, 0]

for i in data.index:
    if any("Jone" in s for s in data.name[i]):
        jone[i] = 1
    else:
        jone[i] = 0

for i in data.index:
    if any("Elvis" in s for s in data.name[i]):
        elvis[i] = 1
    else:
        elvis[i] = 0

for i in data.index:
    if any("Tom" in s for s in data.name[i]):
        tom[i] = 1
    else:
        tom[i] = 0

for i in data.index:
    if any("Tonny" in s for s in data.name[i]):
        tonny[i] = 1
    else:
        tonny[i] = 0

data['Jone'] = jone
data['Elvis'] = elvis
data['Tom'] = tom
data['Tonny'] = tonny
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import  pandas as pd;
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

def getDfIds(df):
    ids = []
    for i in df.index:
        ids.append(df.iloc[i,0])
    return ids

# create  headers
def createHeaders(df,ids):
    headers = []
    for i in df.index: 
        names = (df.iloc[i,1]).split('/')
        for index in range(len(names)):
            headers.append(names[index].strip())
    headers = list(set(headers))
    headers.insert(0,"id")
    return headers

# create body
def createBody(df,headers,ids):
    # set default values 0
    data = [[0 for i in range(len(headers))] for j in range(len(df.index))]

    for i in df.index: 
        data[i][0] = ids[i]
        names = (df.iloc[i,1]).split('/')
        for ind in range(len(names)):
            name = names[ind].strip()
            inde = headers.index(name)
            data[i][inde] = 1
    return data

ids = getDfIds(df)
headers = createHeaders(df,ids)
body = createBody(df,headers,ids)

# create new data set
df = pd.DataFrame(body, columns = headers)
print df;
```